# Bootstrap photos not displaying in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a carousel of photos into my Laravel app's home page, but for some reason, the photo's do not show. If I slip the image in alone without the carousel divs, then the image appears, but when I use the carousel code, the images stop appearing. As you can see I am using a blade to include the other files to keep my code broken up modularly.

**app.blade.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/app.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
@include('inc.navbar')
@include('inc.imageslider')

<div class="container mt-3">
    @if(request()->is('/'))
        @include('inc.showcase')
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            @include('inc.messages')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            @include('inc.sidebar')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**imageslider.blade.php**

```html
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background.png" alt="background image">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background2.png" alt="background image">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background3.png" alt="background image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to change links to <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/background.png') }}">
        </div> </div> but still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your imageslider.blade.php with below code. you missed the active class. It will work now.

```
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/background.png" alt="background image">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background2.png" alt="background image">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background3.png" alt="background image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```